Define tick labels in PGFPlots with a variable
When I try to specify ticks / tick labels in PGFPlots using a variable (for automatic report generation for example), it works for the ticks, but not for the tick labels.
Here is the code I use:
\def\UMMmin{4.0}
\def\UMMmax{4.25}
\def\UMMticks{4.00,4.05,4.10,4.15,4.20,4.25}
\def\UMMticklabels{4.00,4.05,4.10,4.15,4.20,4.25}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=\UMMmin,
                 ymax=\UMMmax,
                 ytick=\UMMticks,
                 yticklabels=\UMMticklabels]
        \addplot+[mark size=1pt] table [x index=0,y index=1,header=false] {./data/data_umm.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Once again, no problem with the min, max, ticks' positions efinition, but impossible to specifiy the tick labels...
Does anybody has already faced this issue ?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

You need to expand \UMMticklabel when setting ytickslabel:
yticklabels/.expand once=\UMMticklabels

Full example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\UMMmin{4.0}
\def\UMMmax{4.25}
\def\UMMticks{4.00,4.05,4.2}
\def\UMMticklabels{A,B,C}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      ymin=\UMMmin,
      ymax=\UMMmax,
      ytick=\UMMticks,
      yticklabels/.expand once=\UMMticklabels
    ]
    \addplot+[mark size=1pt]
    table [x index=0,y index=1,header=false] {
      1 4.1
      2 4.2
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thank you very much, this solution works perfectly!
